# Read extended ascii character from a file

Tags: c++, qt

I want to read a file char by char and convert these character to decimal ascii values. But at this point I came across a problem. When I read the file, I cannot see some ascii character on my qt terminal (question marks)

```
QString char_Read;
char_Read = fileRO.read(1);
qDebug() << char_Read;
```

My txt file :

```
b`183456789ã~▼
```

my outputs :

```
  "b"
  "`"
  "1"
  "8"
  "3"
  "4"
  "5"
  "6"
  "7"
  "8"
  "9"
  "?"
  "?"
  "~"
  "?"
  "?"
  "?"
  ""
```

Comment: `char`s will be displayed as characters, but if you turn that `char` into an integer... That'll be printed as a number. Waaaait a second. You're reading as a string. That'll take a bit more work. You'll have to transform the string to characters as well.

Comment: @user4581301 `char` or `QChar`?

Comment: I'd go with plain old `char` since you're interested in extended ASCII. `QChar` is a wrapper around 16 bit unicode. That said, make sure you're getting ASCII and not unicode.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see decimal ascii values, you have to convert the read characters to integer before you output them via qDebug(): `qDebug("%d", fileRO.readQChar(1).unicode());`